# SaveRecord error in Access template macro

Tags: ms-access, macros

I'm using a database based on the MS-Access Assets Database template. (You can download it here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-access-asset-tracking-template-6e99a32c-fbda-48a2-89b0-ef0d68b381ec.

I've added a few tables of my own and some VBA code.

On the "Asset Details" form, I can make a change to the current record, then press the "Save and New" button. It runs the embedded macro `cmdSaveAndNew`, which you can see here:

[image: xxxxxxxxx]

I have not modified this macro. But it gives me this error message:

`The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 't Asset Log'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly`

So you know, `t Asset Log` is the **old** name of one of the tables that I added to the database. I cannot figure out why the embedded macro is trying to access it. (In the current version of the database, it's `tAssetLog` with no spaces. I've searched through my VBA code, and it only uses the current spacing.)

I tried the macro in "Single-step" mode. As near as I can tell, the error occurs at the `SaveRecord` line.

I've looked at the properties of all the controls, and I don't see any Data or Events that point to `t Asset Log`. I've run "Compact and Repair" on the database, and also compiled the code in the VBA editor; they didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

open the queries involved with this macro and sanity check that 't Asset Log' is not being used as criteria or in a calculated field...

if you don't see it there, wouldn't hurt to search in VBA for 't Asset Log' - is easily done with the Find feature...but doesn't seem like is here though not sure what the macro does....